# Determine the final Windows user

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

We have a **SQL Server 2008 R2** database whose tables are used by **stored procedures** themselves called by dedicated application code (VBA).

Until now all the final users were accessing the same data but for regulatory compliance they will be split into 2 legal entities and we'll have to ensure each user only accesses his entity's records.
Implementing this restriction at the application level is quite simple but not safe (AFAIK any XLA is easily broken).
So to be safe we must implement it at the database level.

My first idea was to simply change the stored procedures to join on the current caller's entity to transparently filter the records retrieved by the SQL queries.
Unfortunately the access is made via a **generic SQL Server user**, and, from what I've seen on SO and elsewhere, although we are on a full Microsoft infrastructure, there is no way to get the Windows user name.
And indeed all the functions I have tested return the SQL Server user name:

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME();
SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN();
EXEC sp_who
EXEC sp_who2
```

So, unless I've missed something, we'll have to **switch the authentification mode to Windows**.

Then, either join as described above, or:

- create 2 **database roles**, one per legal entity, and manually assign users to each one,
- create **views** dedicated to each legal entity, and restrict their access with the roles.

Is there any other option?

Comment: In SQL Server 2016+, [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) may help. You could control row-level access via Windows group membership using `IS_MEMBER`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-member-transact-sql). That way, Windows group membership would control access to specific rows and that could be leveraged for access to non-SQL resources too.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for the pointer but unfortunately we are stuck with SQL Server 2008 for the time being.

Comment: Without RLS, you can similarly filter rows in your procs based on Windows group membership but would need to do that in each query instead of via security policy. I tagged your question with sql-2008 per your comment; change to sql-2008-r2 if that's what you are using (although it probably doesn't make a difference here).

Comment: @DanGuzman You mean by joining on a legal entity membership criteria like `SELECT * FROM DataTable JOIN MembershipTable ON DataTable.LegalEntity = MembershipTable.LegalEntity WHERE MembershipTable.Username = CURRENT_USER_NAME`? OK for the tag, I've replaced `windows` which is too generic by `sql-server`.

Comment: You could simplify the task by using domain groups too.  Chances are their domain groups will be different based on these entities, and assigning people the proper permissions based on their active directory listings makes your DBA life easier especially when it comes to terminations/hirings.  You just have to add the groups to SQL Server, and give the group access to whichever tables/views they require for their job.

Comment: You have to capture the username from the users' system and match it on the backend to apply the limitation. I am surprised you said you could not get the username from windows and you said you are using Microsoft stack. If the users log into windows server then you should be able to get their username using VBA. Have you tried `environ("username")`?

Comment: @DaveCullum Indeed using domain groups is a good idea, thanks.

Comment: @Ibo Yes getting the user's name on the client side is easy but unsecured as it can easily be spoofed. But spoofing some Windows' identity is far more difficult and is hacking for real, so better if our security is based on Windows' identity rather than a basic text identifier.